# Matlab, Change order in a cell array randomly

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, cell

is it possibly to change the order of a cell array randomly with a function, or shoudl I another way around ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html):

```
>> myCell = {'a', 23, [3 4 5], 'bbb'}
myCell = 
    'a'    [23]    [1x3 double]    'bbb'

>> myCell(:) = myCell(randperm(numel(myCell)))
myCell = 
    'bbb'    'a'    [1x3 double]    [23]
```

This works for n-dimensional cell arrays too:

```
>> myCell = {1, 2; 'a', 'b'}
myCell = 
    [1]    [2]
    'a'    'b'

>> myCell(:) = myCell(randperm(numel(myCell)))
myCell = 
    [1]    'a'
    'b'    [2]
```

Comment: Guess we had about the same solution, I switched `randperm` to the other side to introduce at least a bit of variation.

Comment: Thank you, Dennis, it was just what I was looking for both answers actually

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Yes, there was not much more variation to use :-) +1 for you too

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is as simple as this:

```
x = {10,11,12}
x(randperm(3))=x
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it was obviously pretty simple, Thank you for helping